# How to derive the probability function from information entropy?

Tags: probability, expected-value, information-theory

How to derive the probability function from information entropy?

$H(X)=\sum P(x_i)I(x_i)$

$H(X)=\int P(x)I(x) dx$

Can we get the equation in the form of P=f(H)?

Comment: What is $f(H)$?

Comment: This means expressing P in terms of H.

Comment: So what is $f$ then?

Comment: $f$ means mapping, but I do not know the exact form. Put it simply, I want to move P to the left and move H to the right.

Answer (score 2):

The mapping from the densities or mass functions of random variables to its entropy is many-to-one.

$X \sim U[0, 1]$ and $Y \sim\mathcal{N}\left(\text{any }\mu,\sigma=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi e}}\right)$ have the same entropy of $H(X)=H(Y)=0$.

It seems very unlikely that you could come up with a meaningful inverse, unless you know the class of random  variables that you are considering, or some other information.